# Replace jQuery slide with transition() from Transit

Tags: replace, jquery-animate, transition, slide, jquery-transit

Found this and would love to replace .animate() with .transition() (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit):

[Replace jQuery slide with animate() CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564735/replace-jquery-slide-with-animate-css3/17248898#17248898)

This does not seem to animate, but is instead finished when clicked:

el.transition({ "display": "block", "height": "show"}, 250);

Answer (score 1):

Your sintax is not correct, you can use transit with values like:

opacity, rotate, padding, width, height, x etc.

And what is that 'height: show' there?

Here is an example of usage:

```
JQ(thePanel).transition({
                opacity: 0,
                duration: 200,
                rotate: '+=3deg',
                height: theHeight,
            });
```

You see, also the duration is declarated inside the {}. There's a bunch of examples on http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/#top